# How can I get docker log levels in .NET client for Docker?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, logging, .net-core

I'm using this method for getting logs from containers. It all works OK, but I also need log levels (INFO, ERR, etc.). How can I get them from container with .NET client?

```
private async Task GetLogFromContainer(string containerId)

        var logStream = await _dockerClient.Containers.GetContainerLogsAsync(containerId,
            new ContainerLogsParameters
            {
                Follow = true,
                ShowStderr = true,
                ShowStdout = true,
                Timestamps = true,

            }, default);

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(logStream))
        {
            string line = null;
            while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
            {
                var firstSpaceIndex = line.IndexOf("Z "); // separating timestamp from message 
                
                var gettingDate = line.Substring(0, firstSpaceIndex+1); // getting date string with garbage letters at the beginning
                var firstTwoNumber = gettingDate.IndexOf("2"); // start of the timestamp
                var finalDate = gettingDate.Substring(firstTwoNumber); // getting real timestamp

                var time = DateTime.Parse(finalDate); // parsing timestamp
                var message = line.Substring(firstSpaceIndex + 2).TrimStart(); // getting message 
                var lineToAdd = "[" + time.ToString("G", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru-RU")) + "]" + " " + message; // log line
                
                Console.WriteLine(lineToAdd);
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: They look like this right now]

Comment: what about passing LOGLEVEL as ENV var in docker run time?

Comment: @mulg0r unfortunately it doesn't work. I suppose the issue is in Docker Engine API, that just don't include levels on logs